# C++ - Simple SharedQueue is mutex necessary?

Tags: c++, queue, mutex

I have created a simple "SharedQueue" class which is accessed by 2 threads- one to insert a data, another to receive it. In this example it holds `int`s but it will be extended to become a template class so it can hold everything.

`internalQueue` is just a `std::queue<int>` and `qMtx` is a `std::mutex`.

Below part of implementation:

```
size_t SharedQueue::size() const
{
    return internalQueue.size();
}

bool SharedQueue::empty() const
{
    return internalQueue.empty();
}

int SharedQueue::front()
{
    int retVal;
    qMtx.lock();
    retVal = internalQueue.front();
    qMtx.unlock();
    return retVal;
}

void SharedQueue::push(const int& val)
{
    qMtx.lock();
    internalQueue.push(val);
    qMtx.unlock();
}

void SharedQueue::push(int&& val)
{
    qMtx.lock();
    internalQueue.push(val);
    qMtx.unlock();
}

void SharedQueue::pop()
{
    qMtx.lock();
    internalQueue.pop();
    qMtx.unlock();
}
```

My question is:
Do I need to lock the mutex when calling methods like `size()` or `empty()`?

I was trying to find any example of queue for multithreading but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: You have to ask yourself what `size()` and `empty()` mean in a concurrent scenario.

Comment: If the scenario is that: if empty -> wait 5 seconds, else handle what's inside immediately then it needs locking.. Is that what you meant @juanchopanza?

Comment: I mean that it can be empty when you ask, and immediately become not empty, so the result of the call to `empty()` isn't very useful. Same with `size()`. You'd have to lock the calls plus all code that uses the result of the calls.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must protect those functions as well. You have no idea what size() or empty() is going to be doing; there is no guarantee of atomicity on these functions.

An implementation is free to choose any constant time solution for determining size() and empty(), but this does not imply there *must* be a counter somewhere that "probably" has semi-atomic behaviour.

Comment: Even if they are protected, they aren't much use.